# Excel: How can I add code to a lost focus Event of a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to add code to the *LostFocus* event of the cells in a sheet?

I want to add code to keep the first 50 characters of the cell that loses the focus:

```
If Len(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1) > 50 Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Left$(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1, 47) + "..."
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *Lost Focus* event.  Try this instead

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static OldRange As Range
    If Not OldRange Is Nothing Then
        If Not OldRange.HasFormula Then
            If Len(OldRange.Value) > 50 Then
                OldRange.Value = Left$(OldRange.Value, 47) + "..."
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set OldRange = Target.Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Note, I don't think you want to use `FormulaR1C1` because if you happen to have a formula where the Formula it self is longer than 50 chars, the code as posted would put an invalid formula into the cell.  What I've posted ignores formulas, even if they return a result longer than 50 chars.  If required this could be changed to convert the formula to its truncated result.

Note also that this handles multi-cell selections poorly.  You would have to consider your use case carefully in this regard.

Comment: Thank you for your tips! I ended using the Workbook_SheetChange but using your same logic (with a slightly change)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sheet As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

using that you can see whta you changed too, If you keep a variable with what it changed from you should be able to track it easily